# How can i add additional data to a neural network?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Im currently coding a neural network which consists of 3 layers CNN followed by 3 layers of fully connected layers and the input for my CNN are 4 images.

Now here is my question, is it possible to add an additional input between the fully connected layers and the CNN. I want that the output of the CNN as the input for the fully connected layer plus one input that represents an angle.

Is this somehow possible and feasible with tensorflow keras?

Comment: Yes, you can do that easily using functional api, check out https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional#manipulate_complex_graph_topologies

Comment: ok i looked at it. But im not super sure how to use it correctly. 
Would it be enough to use Concatenate()([x1, x2]), when lets say x1 is the flattened output of my cnn and x2 is the angle information?

Comment: the dimensions should be same except for the one passed. Eg: if flattened output is (1,N), if your angle information also has (1,M), then you can concatenate (because both are 1 dimensional with different number of elements). In this case, after concat you get (1,N+M). If your 1st input is (600, 30, 30, 128) (an image with 600 batch size, 30x30 images with 128 channels, you can concat as long as the spatial dimension  and batch size (600x30x30) is same. which dimension to concat along can also be passed as parameter, here it was the last one (axis=-1), s rest of the dimensions need to be same

Comment: take a look at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/concatenate